# Wordpress 3.6 Custom Post Type & wp_nav_menu > No current-menu-item class

Tags: wordpress, class, navigation, custom-post-type

Having troubles with wordpress 3.6. I create a custom nav using this:

```
add_theme_support("nav_menus");
register_nav_menu('main','Main Nav');
```

and this to display

```
wp_nav_menu
```

With wordpress 3.6 you can add Custom Post Type items to our custom navigation but I still have a problem.

[image: As you can see I can add CPT to my custom menu]

[image: And here is my menu with sub menus]

The problem is:

When I click (in the front end) on the sub menu, for example B-Club, it does not add any class the my parent called: Location de lieux...

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Thanks a lot ! I would be grateful !

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, works now !

I had a problem with my single-post-type.php !

Thanks anyway !